# How to solve $(...((a - b) \cdot y - b) \cdot y \ldots) \cdot y \geq 0$ if there are $n$ subtractions and multiplications?

Tags: inequality

It's a programming task, but I'd like to know if there is a way to solve it mathematically.

I need to check $(...((a - b) \cdot y - b) \cdot y \ldots) \cdot y \geq 0$ if we subtract $b$ and multiply on $y$, $n$ times.

I tried to represent it as

$$a \cdot y^n \geq b \cdot \frac{y^n - 1}{y - 1},$$

but I would like to get rid of big numbers such as $y^n$, because these are incomparable in terms of programming if $n \leq 1 \times 10^{18}$ and $y \leq 1 \times 10^{2}$. Do you have any idea how can it be represented differently?

Comment: Well, if $y>0$, divide both sides by $y^n$ and approximate $1/y^n \to 0$…

Comment: the equation corresponds to a continous (even differentiable) function being less or equal zero. you could try to calculate the boundary (=0) and either by between value or by differential calculus check which side of a point on the boundary is inner/outer of your solution set.

Answer (score 1):

Your correct expression is $ay^n \ge by\frac {y^{n}-1}{y-1}$ because the first term of the geometric series is $by$ and the common ratio is $y$.  Now if $n$ is large and $y \gt 1$, $y^n$ will be huge, so we should divide it out and get
$$a \ge by\frac {1-y^{-n}}{y-1}$$
If you ignore $y^{-n}$ because it is so small compared to $1$, you get 
$$a \ge by\frac {1}{y-1}$$
which has no especially large terms.